# Trigger to update field values from another object

Tags: apex, trigger, after-trigger

I got this scenario where there's two object say A and B, both of them having a field called BCode and Code . Now, if the values match then another field called X in A has to be populated with the value of X which is in object B. I've written a trigger for this on Object B but while trying to dataload few records of B i'm getting this error

> Execution Of AfterUpdate Caused By: System.ListException: Duplicate Id In List.

Can someone please help as to what wrong I'm doing here?
There's no relationship between the two objects.

```
trigger UpdateXField on B__c (after insert,after update){

Set<String> bCode = new set<String>();
List<A__c> updatedAList = new List<A__c>();

for(B__c b:Trigger.New){
    bCode.add(b.Code__c);
}

List<A__c> AList = [SELECT BCode__c,X__c FROM A__c 
                                WHERE RecordType.Name = 'Test' AND BCode__c IN:bCode LIMIT : Limits.getLimitQueryRows() - Limits.getQueryRows()];
if(!AList.isEmpty()){                                
   for(B__c b:Trigger.New){
        for(A__c a:aList){
            if(b.Code__c == a.BCode__c && b.Status__c=='Approved' && b.Flag__c==TRUE){
                a.X__c = b.X__c;  

            }
            else{
                a.X__c = '';
            }


            updatedAList.add(a);
       }
    }

if(!updatedAList.isEmpty()){
    Database.update(updatedAList);
}
} 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are running the for loop on both B and A object records, the same A record can be repeatedly added to the list which is causing the error during the update.

you can either add the A records to be updated into a map by checking if it already added or not and then update the records or

you can optimize it further by storing the value of field X__c in a map against the code__c as a key and running the for loop only once on the queried A records and directly updating the same list

```
trigger UpdateXField on B__c (after insert,after update){

Map<String,String> bCodeXMap = new Map<String,String>();

for(B__c b:Trigger.New){
    if(b.Status__c=='Approved' && b.Flag__c==TRUE)
      bCodeXMap.put(b.Code__c,b.X__c);
}

List<A__c> AList = [SELECT BCode__c,X__c FROM A__c 
                                WHERE RecordType.Name = 'Test' AND BCode__c IN: bCodeXMap.keySet()  LIMIT : Limits.getLimitQueryRows() - Limits.getQueryRows()];

if(!AList.isEmpty()){                                
        for(A__c a:aList){
            if(bCodeXMap.containsKey(a.BCode__c)){
                a.X__c = bCodeXMap.get(a.BCode__c);      
            }
       }
       Database.update(AList);
    }    

}
```

Comment: N.B. `if(!AList.isEmpty())` is superfluous

Comment: Working fine. I used the logic as provided here, first creating a set, then a list and a map. Thanks.

Comment: One more thing, this is working on before insert, before update. There's no relationship between the two objects and so there's no dependency on id's so this works on before insert and update.